# Caminho de Instalação personalizado através do SETUP

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Quando publico  a aplicação do windows form, ele ja gera  o Setup pelo visual Studio 2010 o qual  o qual ao rodar , instala em "arquivos de programas" no windows 7  a Instalação.
Gostaria de criar um diretório de nome c:\CartorioScanner\ e neste diretório ao rodar o Setup, instalar o programa, saberiam como posso fazer isso?
Muito Grato

Comment: Têm como esclarecer um pouco mais sua dúvida? Você quer saber como cria um setup do projeto?

Comment: Isso mesmo Daniel, quando você cria uma versão você  vai no Publish do Visual Studio e gera uma versão para ser instalada em winform.Ai quando vc executa o setup gerado ele por default instala  o programa na pasta de  arquivo de programas do windows.Só que eu não quero que seja assim.Gostaria de gerar uma instalação onde ele me intale num diretório pré-determinado, por exemplo, c:\CartorioScanner\.

Comment: ok, vou postar uma resposta...

Comment: Pessoal deu certo, eu mesmo criei o instalador no Visual Studio  e direcionei para criar no diretório especificado.Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Um dos setups que aprendi que foi bem didático com os desenvolvedores que trabalho é desta maneira, espero que ajude:

passo 1: Crie uma aplicacao de setup.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Junto ao seu projeto web, aplicações e etc. (utilizarei o exemplo do setup project, mas o web setup é semelhante a esses passos)

Passo 2: abra as ações customizadas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui você incluirá seu projeto e entraremos ao passo seguinte

passo 3: Vamos adicionar o projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

passo 4: abra com duplo clique a opção "application folder"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Abrindo esta opção você irá na opção primary output

passo 5 : Insira sua aplicação ao setup.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como eu não tenho nenhuma aplicação em meu solution, não apareceu nenhuma opção na aba, mas como exemplo eu dei uma rabiscada rápida para exemplificar.

Passo 6: Dar ok em tudo e verifique se os itens estão adicionados corretamente.

Neste passo, após confirmar todos os passos feitos na imagem do passo 4 ira aparecer o seu projeto em todas as pastas de: Install, Commit, Rollback, Uninstall. Automaticamente aparecerá as Dll's na pasta "detected dependencies" na aplicação de setup. Após feito isso, dar um build e se funcionar corretamente basta buscar o setup que fica na pasta debug desta aplicação.